# Keras to Pytorch -> troubles with layers and shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am in the process of converting a Keras model to PyTorch and would need your help.

Keras Code:

```py
def model(input_shape):
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv1 = keras.layers.ReLU()(conv1)
    global_average_pooling = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(conv1)
    output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(number_of_classes, activation="softmax")(global_average_pooling )
    return keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

Summary of Model:

[image]

My Code Is:

```py
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        #number_of_classes = data_config.number_of_classes
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(256,128,1) # PyTorch does not support same padding, 
        self.bn1=nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        #self.relu=nn.functional.relu_(16)
        self.avg = nn.AvgPool1d(1)
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        #x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.avg(x)
        output = F.log_softmax(x)
        return output
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Greets!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happens when you run the code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Please see [ask].

Comment: There is a Shape error.. it says that the output is [128] but the output should be [128,1] But i think the PyTorch Model from me isn't the same like the keras model

Comment: Errors have to be included in full in the question itself, else you are leaving people to guess what the problem is.

Comment: why would one want to convert Keras model to PyTorch model ?

Comment: @VasilYordanov bec. one specific System cant handle keras..

Comment: @electricz what system that might be an in-house system or open-source ?

Comment: @VasilYordanov inhouse

Comment: @electricz well I don't want to guess here ... but I am assuming that you are trying to productionaze the model ... if so better switch to an open-source serving container such [tensorflow-serving,](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving)   [TorchServe](https://pytorch.org/serve/) , [KFServing](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/external-add-ons/kserve/kserve/) or other similar one

Answer (score 1):

My Current Code is:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(256,128,1)
        self.batch1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.avgpl1 = nn.AvgPool1d(1, stride=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128,3)
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.batch1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.avgpl1(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x,1)
        x = F.log_softmax(self.fc1(x))
        return x
```

Keras Model Parameters:
[image]

And my Parameters currently are:
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).